# MySQL query sorting correct information

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forum

I'm currently struggling to find out the correct query for what I want to achieve and was wondering if anyone has some bright ideas.
Been at a lost here for quite some days now and just can't find the correct query to get what I need.

**Desired result:**

I currently have fully working forum, with multiple categories, due to the fact that there's multiple categories I would like to make an overview page basically stating the last thread, last post, by whom and at what time per category.

**Here is how my table is structured**

**Name**: forums
**Fields**: id, name

**Name**: forum_threads
**Fields**: id, f_id, subject, author, lastpost

**Name**:
forum_posts
**Fields**: id, t_id, post, author, time

**The actual problem**

I have gotten the query thus far that it displays everything as I want except for one thing, it doesn't get the latest thread subject, everything else seems to be displaying correctly (Note I've disabled forums.id 9 and everything above 12, I don't want to show these results.

```
SELECT forums.id, t.id AS thread_id,
   t.subject,
   t.forum_id,
   t.author, t.lastpost,
   u1.name AS author_name, u1.avatar AS author_avatar,
   u2.name AS lastpost_name, u.avatar AS lastpost_avatar
    COUNT(p.id) AS postscount,  COUNT(DISTINCT (t.id)) AS threadscount,
   forums.name,
   max(p.time) last_post_date
FROM forum_threads t
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = t.author
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = t.lastpost
INNER JOIN forum_posts p ON p.t_id = t.id
INNER JOIN forums ON forums.id = t.forum_id
WHERE forums.id != 9 AND forums.id > 12
GROUP BY  forums.id
ORDER BY forums.id ASC, p.id DESC, last_post_date DESC
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the `thread_id` you're retrieving is correct, and the `subject` column on the `forum_threads` table contains the subject you're expecting, then there is a problem in your display level code rather than your query.  (Since you're pulling `thread_id` from the same row as `t.subject`, if one is correct as you expect, the other should be, too.)

Besides that, and this is slightly off topic, I'd caution you against using constructs such as `WHERE forums.id != 9 AND forums.id > 12`.  Instead, you should have a column in the database for `disabled`, and query against that.  Otherwise you have an unmaintainable mess.

---

In response to the comments, try adding this block of SQL to your `JOIN` clauses:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.forum_id as forum_id, MAX(lastpost) as lastpost
    FROM forum_threads t2
    GROUP BY t2.forum_id) as latest_post_per_forum
  ON latest_post_per_forum.forum_id = t.forum_id
```

and this to your `WHERE` clause:

```
  AND t.lastpost = latest_post_per_forum.lastpost
```

Unfortunately I don't have a convenient MySQL instance at this time to test my syntax, but the gist should be obvious: pull the last post ID out on a per-forum basis and then compare each thread's last post ID to that.

Comment: Well the thread_id links to the same thread as the subject, just that it isn't the latest thread that was posted in.
Appreciate the input on the off-topic situation, I will resolve this as soon as everything is ready, this is to prevent certain forums to be shown to users that aren't logged in.

Comment: You have a couple of options: you can filter on the application side so that you select the thread with the maximum last_post_date from your entire result set (which could get expensive as your site gets busier).  You could also add a subquery, which, in mysql, will be quite bad for performance.  You could also do a second query at the app layer and pass in the list of IDs within the app layer.  I'll add an example of the subquery to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! after playing around with what you've posted I've managed to fix the exact result I've wanted, tho I also had to make a seperate inner join for my counts but it's all working well now!

Would give you kuddo's but need more reputation to do so, so if anyone can do it on my behalf please do it for this legend =)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Just remember that, because MySQL's query planner is the next thing to useless, this is not an optimal query for performance.  If this were any other type of database, the subqueries would be better as CTEs.  I also recommend that you cache the results for a minute or so, so that you're not doing the calculations on each page view.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yeah the results are being cached until a new posts/thread has been made, thank you again so much!